# Fetch results from BigQueryOperator in airflow

Tags: python, google-bigquery, airflow

I am trying to fetch results from `BigQueryOperator` using airflow but I could not find a way to do it. I tried calling the `next()` method in the `bq_cursor` member (available in 1.10) however it returns `None`. This is how I tried to do it

```
import datetime
import logging

from airflow import models
from airflow.contrib.operators import bigquery_operator
from airflow.operators import python_operator


yesterday = datetime.datetime.combine(
    datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(1),
    datetime.datetime.min.time()
)

def MyChequer(**kwargs):
    big_query_count = bigquery_operator.BigQueryOperator(
        task_id='my_bq_query',
        sql='select count(*) from mydataset.mytable'
    )

    big_query_count.execute(context=kwargs)

    logging.info(big_query_count)
    logging.info(big_query_count.__dict__)
    logging.info(big_query_count.bq_cursor.next())

default_dag_args = {
    'start_date': yesterday,
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'project_id': 'myproject'
}

with models.DAG(
        'bigquery_results_execution',
        # Continue to run DAG once per day
        schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(days=1),
        default_args=default_dag_args) as dag:

    myoperator = python_operator.PythonOperator(
        task_id='threshold_operator',
        provide_context=True,
        python_callable=MyChequer
    )

    # Define DAG
    myoperator
```

Taking a look to [bigquery_hook.py](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/contrib/hooks/bigquery_hook.py) and [bigquery_operator.py](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator.py) it seems to be the only available way to fetch the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @kaxil and @Mike for their answers. I found the problem. There is a kind of bug (in my mind) in the  `BigQueryCursor`. As part of the `run_with_configuration`, the `running_job_id` is being returned but never assigned to `job_id` which is used to pull the results in the `next` method. A workaround (not really elegant but good if you do not want to re-implement everything), is assign the `job_id` based on the `running_job_id` in the hook like this

```
big_query_count.execute(context=kwargs)
#workaround
big_query_count.bq_cursor.job_id = big_query_count.bq_cursor.running_job_id
logging.info(big_query_count.bq_cursor.next())
```

Answer (score 7):

I create my own operator using the BigQuery hook whenever I need to get the data from a BigQuery query and use it for something.I usually call this a BigQueryToXOperator and we have a bunch of these for sending BigQuery data to other internal systems.

For example, I have a BigQueryToPubSub operator that you might find useful as an example for how to query BigQuery and then handle the results on a row by row basis, sending them to Google PubSub. Consider the following generalized sample code for how to do this on your own:

```
class BigQueryToXOperator(BaseOperator):
    template_fields = ['sql']
    ui_color = '#000000'

    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(
            self,
            sql,
            keys,
            bigquery_conn_id='bigquery_default',
            delegate_to=None,
            *args,
            **kwargs):
        super(BigQueryToXOperator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.sql = sql
        self.keys = keys # A list of keys for the columns in the result set of sql
        self.bigquery_conn_id = bigquery_conn_id
        self.delegate_to = delegate_to


    def execute(self, context):
        """
        Run query and handle results row by row.
        """
        cursor = self._query_bigquery()
        for row in cursor.fetchall():
            # Zip keys and row together because the cursor returns a list of list (not list of dicts)
            row_dict = dumps(dict(zip(self.keys,row))).encode('utf-8')

            # Do what you want with the row...
            handle_row(row_dict)


    def _query_bigquery(self):
        """
        Queries BigQuery and returns a cursor to the results.
        """
        bq = BigQueryHook(bigquery_conn_id=self.bigquery_conn_id,
                          use_legacy_sql=False)
        conn = bq.get_conn()
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(self.sql)
        return cursor
```

Comment: this is exactly what i have been looking for mike, thanks so much. how do you then call this task in your dag? do you mind showing an example

Comment: also would you know how to pass an x_com value (a single cell retrieved from bq) to a dataflowpython job?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `BigQueryOperator` to save results in a temporary destination table and then use `BigQueryGetDataOperator` to fetch the results as below and then use `BigQueryTableDeleteOperator` to delete the table:

```
get_data = BigQueryGetDataOperator(
    task_id='get_data_from_bq',
    dataset_id='test_dataset',
    table_id='Transaction_partitions',
    max_results='100',
    selected_fields='DATE',
    bigquery_conn_id='airflow-service-account'
)
```

Docs:

- **BigQueryGetDataOperator**: https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/1.10.0/integration.html#bigquerygetdataoperator
- **BigQueryTableDeleteOperator**: https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/1.10.0/integration.html#bigquerytabledeleteoperator

Comment: I saw this option but I would like to perform this in one step without taking care of delete the temp table

Comment: Then you can use the hooks of respective operators and create one operator for that purpose.

Comment: It is essentially copy and paste bigquery operator but it is not the way to go in my mind, probably I will ended up creating a PR to fix this if is required.

Answer (score 3):

Sharing a small example on how to use Big query hook to fetch data :

Below is my demo_bigquery_hook file :

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.contrib.hooks.bigquery_hook import BigQueryHook
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from datetime import *
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger("airflow.task")

# default arguments
default_args = {
    'owner': 'Airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': days_ago(0),
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=2)
}

# initializing dag
dag = DAG(
    'test_bigquery_hook',
    default_args=default_args,
    catchup=False,
    schedule_interval=None,
    max_active_runs=1
)

def get_data_from_bq(**kwargs):
    hook = BigQueryHook(bigquery_conn_id='bigquery_default', delegate_to=None, use_legacy_sql=False)
    conn = hook.get_conn()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT owner_display_name, title, view_count FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions` WHERE creation_date > "2020-09-09" ORDER BY view_count DESC LIMIT 2')
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    print('result', result)
    return result

fetch_data = PythonOperator(
    task_id='fetch_data_public_dataset',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=get_data_from_bq,
    dag=dag
)

fetch_data
```

To test it on local, save the above content in a 'demo_bigquery_hook.py' file and copy it to your dags folder. Open a command promt and execute below commands :

1. `export AIRFLOW_CONN_BIGQUERY_DEFAULT="google-cloud-platform://?extra__google_cloud_platform__project=<gcp_project_Id>"`. Replace gcp_project_id is with the any Gcp project Id. This command will setup the default gcp account.
2. `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=<path_to_your_sa_key>`. where <path_to_your_sa_key> is the path to your Gcp project's service account key.
3. Finally run below command : `airflow test test_bigquery_hook fetch_data_public_dataset 2020-09-02T05:38:00+00:00`. Upon running you will see the below result.

[image]

A few points to note:

1. Query used in this example fetches results from a public dataset provided by Gcp.
2. Bigquery cursor object provides a whole lot of other functions as well. Open this [link](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.12/_api/airflow/contrib/hooks/bigquery_hook/index.html?highlight=bigquery#airflow.contrib.hooks.bigquery_hook.BigQueryCursor) to go through them.
3. Airflow version used for this example is 1.10.12.

Answer (score 2):

The Google provided operators use `BigQueryHook` to get an authenticated connection to BigQuery. That class is the one that resolves the Airflow Connection and creates the Google Cloud credentials. You import it with:

```py
from airflow.contrib.hooks.bigquery_hook import BigQueryHook
```

The [latest docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/bigquery/index.html) say that it has a method "get_client()" that should return the authenticated underlying client. That didn't work on my version of Airflow so I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57782117/329496) to directly create a  `bigquery.client.Client` connection from the internal fields of the hook. Here is the logic:

```py
def read_files_loaded_from_bq(bigquery_conn_id, sql):
    hook = BigQueryHook(bigquery_conn_id=bigquery_conn_id, delegate_to=None, use_legacy_sql=False)
    # this should work with latest version:
    # client = hook.get_client()
    # instead directly create a client using the internals of the hook:
    client = bigquery.Client(project=hook._get_field("project"), credentials=hook._get_credentials())
    query_job = client.query(sql)
    files = []
    for row in query_job:
        file_name = row["file_name"]
        files.append(file_name)
    result = ','.join(files)
    print('found files:', result)
    return result

read_files_loaded = PythonOperator(
    task_id='read_files_loaded',
    provide_context=False,
    python_callable=read_files_loaded_from_bq,
    op_kwargs = {
        "bigquery_conn_id": BIGQUERY_CONN_ID,
        "sql": "select file_name from myproj.mydataset.files_loaded"
    },
    dag=dag
)
```

That would run the query and load the data into a string. You can then use the following to read the results using xcom:

```
"{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='read_files_loaded') }}"
```

This approach seems straight forward if you are just loading a small amount of meta-data to drive the logic of the DAG. If there was any serious data it would probably be better to use the operators move data between tables and buckets without every pulling it into the actual airflow task process.