# How to query Google Big Query in Apache Airflow and return results as a Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

I'm trying to save a bigquery query to a dataframe in a custom Airflow operator.

I've tried using the airflow.contrib.hooks.bigquery_hook and the get_pandas_df method. The task get's stuck on authentication, as it wants me to manually visit a url to authenticate.

As a result, I'm hard coding in authentication. This works, but is definitely not ideal.

Working but not ideal (credentials are hard coded):

```py
def execute(self, context):
        os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'my-file-location.json'
        client = bigquery.Client()

        job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()

        df = client.query(
            self.query,
            location="US",
            job_config=job_config,).to_dataframe()
```

Not working:

```py
def execute(self, context):
    bq  = BigQueryHook(bigquery_conn_id=self.gcp_conn_id, delegate_to=None,use_legacy_sql=True, location='US')
    df = bq.get_pandas_df(self.query)
```

This code get's stuck authenticating. Here is the log: [2019-06-19 12:56:05,526] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - Please visit this URL to authorize this application.

Answer (score 5):

Somehow I can't get [BigQueryPandasConnector](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/16d93c9e45e14179c7822fed248743f0c3fd935c/airflow/contrib/hooks/bigquery_hook.py#L145) working. What I eventually end up with is using the credentials from BigQueryHook to create a normal [bigquery.client.Client](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html) using BigQuery's official Python client.

Here's an example:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

bq_hook = BigQueryHook(bigquery_conn_id=bigquery_conn_id, use_legacy_sql=False)
bq_client = bigquery.Client(project = bq_hook._get_field("project"), credentials = bq_hook._get_credentials())
df = bq_client.query(sql).to_dataframe()
```

Comment: being able to break out to the normal `bigquery.client.Cloud` seems like an obvious need. the documentation had a `hook.get_client()` that should provide an authenticated underlying bigquery client. that didn't work in my airflow instance with a no attribute found error. this solution saved the day.

Answer (score 1):

Complementing the response of @Oluwafemi, now that you have the credentials for the BigQueryHook you can use them to instantiate the [BigQueryPandasConnector](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/16d93c9e45e14179c7822fed248743f0c3fd935c/airflow/contrib/hooks/bigquery_hook.py#L145). According to the documentation, this connector:

> ... allows Airflow to use BigQuery with Pandas without forcing a three legged OAuth connection ...

Here's an example:

```py
def execute(self, context):

    bq = BigQueryHook(bigquery_conn_id=self.gcp_conn_id, delegate_to=None,use_legacy_sql=True, location='US')
    pd = BigQueryPandasConnector(bq._get_field('project'), bq.get_service())
    df = pd.read_gbq(self.query)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like no service account or key path is specified for the hook.

Here is a guide to setting up GCP connection.
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.3/docs/howto/connection/gcp.rst

Set [`AIRFLOW_CONN_BIGQUERY_DEFAULT`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.3/airflow/contrib/hooks/bigquery_hook.py#L55) environment variable in your airflow config file.

You can go the way of using `key_path` query parameter if the credentials are available in a path accessible to your airflow process. 

Otherwise, set `key_dict` query parameter to URL encoded JSON content of the credentials file.

```
AIRFLOW_CONN_BIGQUERY_DEFAULT=google-cloud-platform://?extra__google_cloud_platform__key_path=%2Fkeys%2Fkey.json&extra__google_cloud_platform__scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform&extra__google_cloud_platform__project=airflow&extra__google_cloud_platform__num_retries=5
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried your soluton by adding AIRFLOW_CONN_BIGQUERY_DEFAULT to airflow.cfg but I'm getting the same error. I setup the credentials including keypaths in the UI under "admin -> connections".  Creating a BigQueryHook object works, get_pandas() still has auth issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can solve your problem using the BigQueryHook you can put it inside any python operator task, it works for me:

```
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.bigquery import BigQueryHook
from pandas import DataFrame


## inside the operator
your_conn_id = 'your_connection_id'
your_sql     = 'sql_to_do_in_bq'
bq_hook = BigQueryHook(bigquery_conn_id=your_conn_id, delegate_to=None, use_legacy_sql=False)
conn = bq_hook.get_conn()
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(your_sql)
df= DataFrame( cursor.fetchall() )
```