# execute sql code which is embedded in a file in DAG

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, google-bigquery

[Fetch results from BigQueryOperator in airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53565834/fetch-results-from-bigqueryoperator-in-airflow/58903908#58903908)

I followed the suggestion in above link, the solution works and it is good and it works if my sql is a single line. but if SQL code is large and place it in a file and reference the file in the function then fails.

```
def MyChequer(**kwargs):
big_query_count = bigquery_operator.BigQueryOperator(
    task_id='my_bq_query',
    sql='/dags/sqls/invalidTable.sql'
)
```

Then I get error : BigQuery job failed. Final error was: {'reason': 'invalidQuery', 'location': 'query', 'message': 'Syntax error: Unexpected identifier "dags" at [1:1]'}

Normally I use in following way and the below works

```
BigQueryOperator(
        task_id='invalidXXX',
        use_legacy_sql=False,
        sql='/dags/sqls/invalid_v1.sql',
        destination_dataset_table=targetTable,
        create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
        write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
        dag=dag
    )
   dag = DAG('invalidXXX', 
    default_args=default_args, 
    description='', 
    schedule_interval="0 5 * * *",
    catchup=False,
    template_searchpath=['/home/airflow/stgAirflow/']
   )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I got this fixed. It means, when dag is executed, the sql code which is in a file is used and executed. Not sure if its a optimized solution. so any more suggestions, are welcome.

```
//define 
class SQLTemplatedPythonOperator(PythonOperator):
    template_ext = ('.sql',)

//modify function
def loadCSV(**kwargs):
    print("inside loadCSV")
    query = kwargs['templates_dict']['query']
    big_query_count = bigquery_operator.BigQueryOperator(
        task_id='my_bq_query',
        sql=query,

//dag - task
SQLTemplatedPythonOperator(
    task_id='invalidBBDToCSV',
    templates_dict={'query': 'invalidBBD.sql'},
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=loadCSV,
    dag=dag,
//dag
dag = DAG('invalidBBDLoad', 
    default_args=default_args, 
    description='DAG data', 
    schedule_interval="0 11 * * *",
    catchup=False,
    template_searchpath=['/home/stgairflow/dags/sqls'], 
    user_defined_macros={'myProjectId': myProjectId,}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like error is coming from trying to execute this string `'/dags/sqls/invalid_v1.sql'` as sql...which isn't valid.

Can you read in the file contents there if you want to keep the sql in a separate file? Seems like the sql arg is expecting an actual sql statement.

Comment: yes, I agree, it is interpreting the string as SQL and failing. Which is obvious, but normally, In a DAG, I give a 'template_searchpath' but in this case it is not DAG, it is a function(def MyChequer) and inside the function Operator. I dont know how I can make the function/operator interpret the sql search path...so I am looking for some help if there is any body who has come across and what logic is used to fix.

Comment: Yeah, kind of a bummer that the docs say they support parsing template files: ```    :param sql: the sql code to be executed (templated)
    :type sql: Can receive a str representing a sql statement,
        a list of str (sql statements), or reference to a template file.
        Template reference are recognized by str ending in '.sql'.```

but reading the code [here](https://airflow.apache.org/_modules/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator.html#BigQueryOperator), the template location is just going to get run here: `if isinstance(self.sql, str):`...there's no template handling.